# Attempting to fill medians of value based on a group by clause but getting an ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have data that looks like this:

```
    Location+Type                                       tract     state_abbr year   tract_state_year    County_name     hpi
0   Census Tract 201, Autauga County, Alabama: Sum...   1001020100  AL  2012    1001020100AL2012    Autauga County  134.41
1   Census Tract 201, Autauga County, Alabama: Sum...   1001020100  AL  2013    1001020100AL2013    Autauga County  129.82
2   Census Tract 201, Autauga County, Alabama: Sum...   1001020100  AL  2014    1001020100AL2014    Autauga County  135.34
3   Census Tract 201, Autauga County, Alabama: Sum...   1001020100  AL  2015    1001020100AL2015    Autauga County  134.66
4   Census Tract 201, Autauga County, Alabama: Sum...   1001020100  AL  2016    1001020100AL2016    Autauga County  140.84
```

I want to apply this formula:

```
medians = (df.groupby(['year', 'state_abbr', 'County_name'])['hpi']
             .transform(lambda x: x.median() if x.notnull().any() else np.nan)
          )
df['hpi'] = df['hpi'].fillna(medians)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 151291 elements, new values have 152159 elements
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the reason you went down the lambda function road is because you want medians excluding nulls for each group. Pandas' median function actually already works that way, so you can simply write:

```
new_hpi = (df
           .groupby(['year', 'state_abbr', 'County_name'])['hpi']
           .transform('median'))
```

To can now just replace the original 'hpi' column with the values.

```
df.loc[:, 'hpi'] = new_hpi
```

Or in one line:

```
df.loc[:, 'hpi'] = (df
                    .groupby(['year', 'state_abbr', 'County_name'])['hpi']
                    .transform('median'))
```